# Is it possible that enriched iron can "lose" it's enrichness?

Tags: spectroscopy, radioactivity

I am doing Mössbauer spectroscopy at room temperature while using my source as a $^{57}$Co and using as my absorber enriched iron. The result I got for some reason is much more similar to iron than enriched iron, I compared my results to the results that appear in this paper (page 3, table 1) :

http://web.mit.edu/dvp/www/Work/8.14/dvp-mossbauer-paper.pdf

I am trying to think why this can happen. I wonder if is it possible that enriched iron can "lose" it's richness and become with spectrum like iron. The second option that I have is that there is mistake in the laboratory by tagging the matter as "enriched iron" instead just iron.

Comment: Please define  "enriched iron" in your system, and how you did or didn't verify the quality of your absorber.

Comment: Did you actually order Fe-57 enriched material?

Comment: @JonCuster I am not sure what are you saying

Comment: @CarlWitthoft According to my understanding, this is what I define enriched Iron :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide
I conculdted that in my experiment , the spectrum is much similar to the one of the iron- Fe57,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enrichment means that the abundance of a particular isotope of the material is heightened compared to what you would have in the naturally occurring material. No, that level of enrichment does not change.

Iron oxide has absolutely nothing at a to do with enrichment, but instead, is a chemical compound. Yes, the chemical composition of a material can change over time. In particular, iron can oxidize.

Based on what you write, and based on the standard Mössbauer lab experiment, my guess is that there is a confusion of terms, and a misunderstanding, and that actually you have a block of iron.

Comment: Thank you, seems resonable.
I assume the reason that the enrichment does not change is due to the fact that the isotopes in that matter is stable?

Comment: safe for radioactive decay, yes, but that would give you a different chemical element